# javacv merging image and mp3 creates a mp4 longer than the original mp3

Tags: java, video, mp3, mp4, javacv

I am using the following code to merge an mp3 and an image

```
IplImage ipl = cvLoadImage(path2ImageFile);
int height = ipl.height();
int width = ipl.width();
if(height%2!=0) height = height+1;
if(width%2!=0) width = width+1;

OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage grabberConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();  
FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(path2OutputFile,width,height); 
FrameGrabber audioFileGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(path2AudioFile);
try 
{  
    audioFileGrabber.start();

    recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264 );//AV_CODEC_ID_VORBIS
    recorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);//AV_CODEC_ID_MP3 //AV_CODEC_ID_AAC

    recorder.setFormat("mp4");  
    recorder.setAudioChannels(2);
    recorder.start();  

    Frame frame = null;
    //audioFileGrabber.getFrameNumber()
    while ((frame = audioFileGrabber.grabFrame())!=null) 
    {   recorder.record(grabberConverter.convert(ipl));  
        recorder.record(frame);
    }

    recorder.stop();  
    audioFileGrabber.stop();
 }
```

This produces an mp4, but it is about 1 and a half minutes longer.
Why does this happen?
Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: What does this extra 1 and half minutes contain (_eg:_ any picture or sound)?

Answer (score 2):

Was a nice issue to solve. IMO, The issues seems to be because of two reasons

- The frame rate of video in this case needs to be same as that of Audio, so that is there is no time increase
- The audio frames while being written should be written at the same timestamp

Below is final code which works for me

```java
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.*;


public class AudioExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path2ImageFile = "WhatsApp Image 2018-12-29 at 21.54.58.jpeg";
        String path2OutputFile = "test.mp4";
        String path2AudioFile = "GMV_M_Brice_English_Greeting-Menus.mp3";

        FFmpegFrameGrabber imageFileGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(path2ImageFile);
        FFmpegFrameGrabber audioFileGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(path2AudioFile);
        try {
            audioFileGrabber.start();
            imageFileGrabber.start();

            FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(path2OutputFile,
                    imageFileGrabber.getImageWidth(), imageFileGrabber.getImageHeight());

            recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);//AV_CODEC_ID_VORBIS
            recorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);//AV_CODEC_ID_MP3 //AV_CODEC_ID_AAC
            recorder.setSampleRate(audioFileGrabber.getSampleRate());
            recorder.setFrameRate(audioFileGrabber.getAudioFrameRate());
            recorder.setVideoQuality(1);
            recorder.setFormat("mp4");
            recorder.setAudioChannels(2);
            recorder.start();

            Frame frame = null;

            Frame imageFrame = imageFileGrabber.grab();
            while ((frame = audioFileGrabber.grab()) != null) {
                recorder.setTimestamp(frame.timestamp);
                recorder.record(imageFrame);
                recorder.record(frame);
            }
            recorder.stop();
            audioFileGrabber.stop();
            imageFileGrabber.stop();
        } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception | FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I removed the opencv for image, since we can use another framegrabber to get the image as a frame also. Also you can see the audio generated is of same size as the mp3

[image: Same size]

## Attempt #2

Since the first attempt was using same framerate for Video and Audio, which was causing some issue, I thought of fixing the framerate and then interleaving the audio on top

```java
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.*;


public class AudioExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path2ImageFile = "/Users/tarunlalwani/Downloads/WhatsApp Image 2018-12-29 at 21.54.58.jpeg";
        String path2OutputFile = "/Users/tarunlalwani/Downloads/test.mp4";
        String path2AudioFile = "/Users/tarunlalwani/Downloads/GMV_M_Brice_English_Greeting-Menus.mp3";

        FFmpegFrameGrabber imageFileGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(path2ImageFile);
        FFmpegFrameGrabber audioFileGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(path2AudioFile);
        try {
            audioFileGrabber.start();
            imageFileGrabber.start();

            FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(path2OutputFile,
                    imageFileGrabber.getImageWidth(), imageFileGrabber.getImageHeight());

            recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);//AV_CODEC_ID_VORBIS
            recorder.setAudioCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);//AV_CODEC_ID_MP3 //AV_CODEC_ID_AAC
            recorder.setSampleRate(audioFileGrabber.getSampleRate());
            int frameRate = 30;
            recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);
            recorder.setFormat("mp4");
            recorder.setAudioChannels(2);
            recorder.start();

            Frame frame = null;

            Frame imageFrame = imageFileGrabber.grab();
            int frames = (int)((audioFileGrabber.getLengthInTime() / 1000000f) * frameRate) + 1;
            int i = 0;

            //create video using fixed images and framerate
            while (i ++ <frames) {
                recorder.record(imageFrame);
            }

            // Add audio to given timestamps
            while ((frame = audioFileGrabber.grabFrame()) != null) {
                recorder.setTimestamp(frame.timestamp);
                recorder.record(frame);
            }

            recorder.stop();
            audioFileGrabber.stop();
            imageFileGrabber.stop();
        } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception | FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works in VLC, but in the standard windows media player the sound can be heard, but the screen is black. I am using winows 10.

Comment: I don't have windows to test. May be this has something to do with the video codec chosen?

Comment: on the javacv forum they say it might have something to do with me recording either to few or too many frames. I should only record as many frames as the maximum framerate and apparently that setFrameRate function sets the maximum framerate. The actual frame rate is set when you actually use setTimestamp to set a frame. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacv/Wr28ZNq2se0 I am still having a hard time understanding all this unfortunately :( The generated videos ... work and don't work depending on ... I don't know on what exactly ... :(

Comment: If I upload to youtube I get a few seconds of it working and then see "Video not available". There's clearly still something wrong :(

Comment: changing recorder.setVideoQuality(); from 0 to 1 seems to have worked. Don't understand why exactly.

Comment: Lot of things are unclear because there is no documentation which says you should ideally do this or do that. This is more of learning by hit n trial

Comment: You can say that again!

Comment: @Para, See the updated answer. I hope the new code helps you out. You can use a fixed frameRate in this one

Comment: modified it a bit to account for the fact that I am using more than one image, but otherwise, works like a charm. Thank you so much for all the help. I had no idea you could write the video and the audio separately.

Comment: any one has this error ? `org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber$Exception: avformat_open_input() error -22: Could not open input "‪C:\Users\Developper\sounds\sound.mp3"`